# How to remove preinstalled languages in ABP framework in microservice template?

Tags: c#, localization, microservices, abp

I use microservice template and language management module. It adds about 10 different languages and I want to have only 2. I tried to limit it using `AbpLocalizationOptions` but it didn't help.

I tried to write the following code in my `Shared Localization` module

```
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Languages.Clear(); // Clear existing languages to redefine them

    options.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("en", "en", "English"));
    options.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("de", "de", "Deutsch"));

});
```

Also, tried to remove everything from database directly, but they come back after restarting the app.

Using version 7.4.5

Comment: Did you remove the localization from the domain module ?

Comment: @Manuel1234 no, I have microservices. Should I remove it from each service? wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization languages are defined in the `AdministrationServiceDomainModule` (under **services/administration** folders). So, you can configure the localization languages there.

Alternatively, you can configure the localization languages in your final application. For example, if you selected the MVC UI, you can configure the localization in the `MyProjectNameWebModule` (under **apps/web** folders), or for Blazor `MyProjectNameBlazorModule` (under **apps/blazor** folders):

```cs
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Languages.Clear();

    options.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("en", "en", "English"));
    options.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("de", "de", "Deutsch"));

});
```

Comment: thanks! indeed you need to write it in Administration Domain module. But I am wondering, if I can do that if I have angular app?